# Вызов события dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть dropdownlist. И у него есть событие SelectedIndexChanged. И есть проблема, если я загружаю проект, и копирую ссылку т.е. у меня одновременно открыты 2 страницы. На одной выбираю в dropdown значение, потом на второй потом возвращаюсь на первую но уже не выбираю значение а просто иду дальше. И тогда SelectedIndexChanged уже не отработает, а мне нужно что бы отработало. Как можно вызвать его выполнение в "ручную"?
И вторая часть вопроса. Как проверить сработало это событие или нет? Я так понимаю просто проверить на true или false не получиться.

Comment: Зачем вам ловить событие  SelectedIndexChanged? Да, вы его и правда так не отловите. Используйте ваш SelectedIndex и всё. Или делайте "таймерные ловушки" в сочетание с cookie (они "не перетираются") можно вычислить что подсунули "старую" страницу.

Comment: Используйте jquery/ajax/скриптовый-подзапрос вместо обычных POST/GET и такой проблемы просто не будет. (потому что кнопка назад не будет работать)

Comment: @nick_n_a слишком много возни будет с изменением логики крупного проекта, как вы поняли я думаю это будет просто костыль. То есть не как нельзя проверить отработал indexChanged или нет?

Comment: Обычно на сайтах просто не предусматривают "такой хитроумный" метод работы. Движение обычно идёт вперёд. Вместо кнопки назад делается "ссылка" назад, которая задаёт "правильное" поведение "назад". Событие нормально срабатывает, а то о чём вы пишите я бы назвал "обмануть" браузер.

Comment: это я бы назвал "работа с  устаревшей страницей". Обычно так не делают. В сессии можно считать запросы и проверять номер запроса в input hiden,  если меньше - так и писать - страница устарела. Второй вариант - сбрасывать select в default перед отправкой post запроса (а отправлять нужное), но к сожелению для c# будет много возни, надо ведь отправить выбраное значение, но это стаботает, т.к. кнопка назад даст то состояние которое было последним перед post.

Comment: @nick_n_a да это чисто теоретически смоделированная ситуация которой не когда не будет, но этот баг дали мне и править его нужно мне, а то что вы описываете действительно сложновато для меня будет. Вот и ищу способ отловить событие.

Comment: "а просто иду дальше"... стоп, тогда событие и не сработает - вы же ничего не меняли. Меняйте js-скриптом хотя бы selected index на 1-е значение, тогда он вызовется. Если вам подойдёт "2 раза" то можете просто з Page_Load вызвать SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: @nick_n_a пока к такому же решению и пришёл, но хотел более прямой "костыль" но похоже придётся делать так)

Comment: @Андрей А откуда по вашему, 1-я страница должна узнать, что на 2-й вы че-то там нажали? То что они были возвращены с одного uri не отменяет того, что для браузера это два отдельных объекта. Поэтому тут два варианта. 1. Создавать cookie в ответ на обработку SelectedIndexChanged и организовать через JS периодическую проверку наличия этих куков. 2. С помощью JS, а именно ajax опрашивать сервер на предмет выбранного в SelectedIndex значения.